# cURL does not return anything

Tags: php, curl, localhost, http-status-code-302

cURL returns nothing when on server. Everything works well on localhost, but when it's in remote hosting getSearchResults() returns nothing (or 302 header). Is this something wrong with server configuration (tried 2 different). Can it be something with CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION? Tried both true and false on localhost - still works. On remote hosting it's not allowed to follow location for some reason, but if it works without on local I don't think that matters.

```
<?php
class cURL
{
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private static $tmpfname;

    public function __construct($username,$password) {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->makeCookies($username, $password);
    }

    private function makeCookies($username, $password) {
        self::$tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "Cookie");
        $useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, self::$tmpfname);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, self::$tmpfname);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://vk.com/login.php");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "email={$username}&pass={$password}");
        ob_start();
        curl_exec($ch);
        ob_end_clean();
        curl_close($ch);
        unset($ch);
    }

    private function getHTML($url){
        $useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, self::$tmpfname);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, self::$tmpfname);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
        $contents = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $contents;
    }

    public function getSearchResults($songname) {
        $songname = urlencode($songname); 
        $contents = $this->getHTML("http://vk.com/search?c[section]=audio&c[q]={$songname}");
        return $contents;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I've never heard of a specific cURL option being disabled on hosting like that. Contact your host or switch.

Comment: @ceejayoz it's not curl option being disabled, `FOLLOWLOCATION` is disabled if PHP runs in safe mode.

Comment: @heroix Friendly reminder! Please use protected instead of private. It allows for extensibility and unit tests later and is considered a good practice.

Comment: @Ranty I'd call that disabled. You really should get a host without safe mode, your life will be much easier. It's so useless they've deprecated it in PHP 5.3 onwards. http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php

Answer (score 1):

A 302 code is a redirect, so you'll need to be able to use `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to get anything useful out of it.

Comment: Also, instead of using `ob_start()` and `ob_end_clean()` to capture the results of cURL, consider setting the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option.  It makes `curl_exec()` return the result as a string instead of outputting it.
If you're looking to suppress the output, use `CURLOPT_MUTE`.

Comment: @GigaWatt: Nice recommendation, should put that as an answer so doesn't get lost in noise.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of implementations of redirecting mechanism on web for web servers that run php in safe mode. For example, [here](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#102121) (the first place you should look it for actually) is the one I one day modified for my own script. It can process multiple redirects and is written in a way that you can easily understand and modify it.